# Using svyrecvar to get the variance of a statistic in the "survey" R package

Tags: r, survey

I am writing an extension to the `survey` R package. My function estimates kurtosis with complex survey data, but I am not sure how to get the standard error of these statistics, like the output from existing functions like `svymean` and `svytotal`.

```
svykurt <- function(
    x,
    design,
    na.rm = FALSE,
    excess = TRUE
) {

  if (!inherits(design, "survey.design"))
    stop("design is not a survey design")

  x <- model.frame(x, design$variables, na.action = na.pass)
  x <- as.matrix(x)

  if (ncol(x) > 1)
    stop("Only calculate kurtosis one variable at a time")

  if(na.rm){
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  }

  pweights <- 1/design$prob
  psum <- sum(pweights)
  mean_x <- svymean(x, design, na.rm = na.rm)
  var_x <- svyvar(x, design, na.rm = na.rm)

  m4 <- sum(pweights * (x - mean_x)^4) / psum
  kurt <- m4 / var_x^2

  if (excess) {
    kurt <- kurt - 3
  }

  class(kurt) <- "svykurt"

  return(kurt)

}

print.svykurt <- function(x) {
  m <- as.matrix(x, ncol = 1)
  rownames(m) <- names(x)
  colnames(m) <- "kurtosis"

  print(m)
}
```

At the moment, I am just printing kurtosis without the standard error.

```
data(api)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
svykurt(x = ~api00, dclus1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, I eventually want to assign the output to class `svystat` and print a matrix containing both values, as in `svymean(x = ~api00, dclus1, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Looking at `survey` [source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/survey/src/R/multistage.R), I can see that `svymean` and `svytotal` use a higher-level function called `svrecvar`, e.g.,

```
attr(total, "var")<-v<-svyrecvar(x/design$prob,design$cluster,
                                     design$strata, design$fpc,
                                   postStrata=design$postStrata)
```

I am just not sure how to apply this to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the kurtosis, you are much better off working with `svycontrast` than with `svyrecvar`. You can write the variance and fourth central moment in terms of the raw moments (following the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237558/kurtosis-expressed-in-raw-moments)) and then transform

```
> moments<-svymean(~enroll+I(enroll^2)+I(enroll^3)+I(enroll^4), dstrat)
> moments
                  mean         SE
enroll      5.9528e+02 1.8509e+01
I(enroll^2) 5.4895e+05 4.0250e+04
I(enroll^3) 7.5137e+08 1.0066e+08
I(enroll^4) 1.3348e+12 2.7683e+11
> 
> central_moments<-svycontrast(moments, list(mu4=quote(-3*enroll^4+6*enroll^2*`I(enroll^2)`-4*enroll*`I(enroll^3)`+`I(enroll^4)`),
sigma2=quote(`I(enroll^2)`-enroll^2)))
> central_moments
            nlcon         SE
mu4    3.3618e+11 1.0458e+11
sigma2 1.9459e+05 2.3116e+04
> 
> 
> svycontrast(central_moments, quote(mu4/(sigma2*sigma2)))
          nlcon     SE
contrast 8.8783 1.5678
```

As a general guide, if you have an explicit formula for a statistic in terms of moments or cell counts or proportions, it's easier to use `svycontrast` and if you have an estimation equation or maximisation problem it's easier to use `svyrecvar`.

To use `svyrecvar` you would need to work out or look up the influence functions for the kurtosis, which is likely to be feasible but a bit annoying. If you do work out the influence functions, it's actually more straightforward to use `svytotal` to work out the variance

For example, in `svyVGAM:::svy_vglm.survey.design` there's a lot of code to fit a VGAM model and work out its influence functions, followed by

```
    v <- vcov(svytotal(inffuns, design))
    dimnames(v) <- list(names(coef(fit)), names(coef(fit)))
```

to do the variance computation.